AI for dubbing across languages
I have about 2 hours of video that I want to dub across languages, e.g. French to English. I have the speakers on separate tracks and without vocal fillers ("uh", "mmm", etc.). I would like an AI, or web service, that:

takes a short audio file in a language and produces a file in another language with similar tone of voice, emotion, and intonation;

lets me control the translation, e.g. I can change the translation of "faire" from "make" to "do";

lets me control the duration of the output utterance;

can imitate the voice of the original speaker ("vocal cloning"), so that the vocal fillers sound natural when I add them back after the translation;

can do all this via an API, or ideally has a Python SDK.


When I searched and tested, FlexClip and Speechify seem to use text-to-speech that does not imitate the original voice, WavelAI doesn't let me control the translation, and Synthesis seems to require a video and failed to produce a result when I tried it.
I found that ElevenLabs is closest: it has an API, I can provide samples for vocal cloning and pass the translated text in a CSV file. It don't seem able to control duration, though. Also I would like to test a few more, if any, before committing to a single provider.
What other state-of-the-art dubbing tools exist at the moment?
